# Why Facebook encrypts an app secret code when access_token api are returned?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, encryption, access-token

Why Facebook encrypts an app secret code when access_token api are returned?

Is there any something special purpose?

Currently, according to my tests, access token required apis can use both two types.
(raw app secret code and app secret code encrypted via bearer)

Even though I following a guideline that the code used in server side only, do I need to get encrypted access_token using the api?

Or don't care to use it just by assembling (client_id|app_secret_code) ?

Thank you first for your reply.